# Включение файла данных в исполняемый файл

Tags: c++

Допустим, у меня есть файл `1.txt` в папке проекта. Как считать из него данные?
Например, `.cpp` файлы подключаются через `#include "file.cpp/.h"`. А как быть с таким файлом?

Мне надо чтобы этот файл упаковался вместе с моей программой в один файл.

Comment: Вы осознаете то, что h файлы подключаются на этапе препроцессора, а Вам похоже нужно на этапе исполнения? или вы хотите включить текстовый файл внутрь cpp на этапе препроцессора (компиляции)?

Comment: Да, на этапе исполнения мне нужен доступ именно к этому файлу

Comment: Используйте [std::ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/)

Comment: @ThreadShakur вам прямой путь в документацию почитать о файловом вводе выводе. P.S.: std::ifstream/std::ofstream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если VS:

1) Создаётся файл ресурсов.

2) В ресурсы добавляется новый файл (через контекстное меню) НЕИЗВЕСТНОГО ЕЩЁ КОМПИЛЯТОРУ типа, например BINARY. Если не уверены что добавилось, то заходите в .rc файл и правьте руками.
Будет строка типа:

```
IDR_BINARY4             BINARY                  "1.txt"
```

3) Во время работы программы обращаться стандартными средствами:
Пример кода:

```
HRSRC   hRes = FindResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(uID), _T("BINARY")); // модуль, ID-ресурса, тип ресурса (да, прямо текстом)
if(!hRes)
{
    return FALSE;
}
DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hRes); // далее по методичке MSDN
HGLOBAL hResMem = LoadResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), hRes);
PBYTE pResource = (PBYTE)LockResource(hResMem);
```

Answer (score 7):

На основании Вашего [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547115/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0/547188#comment699342_547188) становится ясно, что нужно встроить текстовый файл непосредственно в исполняемый `*.exe` файл. Такого рода задачу можно решить разными способами, например:

- Использовать файл ресурсов и компилятор ресурсов для соответствующей ОС (или IDE). Например, для [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381042(v=vs.85).aspx).
- Преобразовать с помощью утилит типа [xxd](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=xxd&category=1&russian=0) Ваш файл в массив данных и включить его непосредственно в код, например:

  ```
  unsigned char txt[] = { 
      0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x20, 0x57, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x21, 0x0a };
  ```

Какое решение будет для Вас оптимальным зависит от используемой ОС, IDE и необходимости в кросс-платформенности подхода.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что человек спрашивает по сути, как ему в проекте (как я понимаю, на Visual C++) обратиться к файлу, который лежит в папке с проектом. В этом случае - надо учесть, что текущим каталогом при запуске **из IDE** становится не папка, в которой лежит `.sln`-файл проекта, а в которой лежат исходники и `.vcxproj` (для Visual Studio). И именно в нее и надо укладывать этот `1.txt`.

Если ошибся в трактовке вопроса - мои извинения, тогда смотрите ответ @Xambey.

Comment: Текущая папка для отлаживаемого проекта задается через Debugging - Working Directory (по умолчанию она установлена в $(ProjectDir), что попадает под ваш ответ).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Ну, как-то не приходилось пользоваться... Все настройки я, понятно, не знаю :(

Comment: Да вы абсолютно правы! Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @ThreadShakur Что именно? Как положить в папку файл?...

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream in("1.txt"); //открываем файл для чтения через поток ifstream
if(!in.is_open()) return EXIT_FAILURE;
while(!in.eof()){ //пока конец файла не достигнут
   //считывайте например через getline(in, какая-то строка куда запишем);
   //что то делаете с этим
}
in.close(); //закрываем файл
```

Comment: Надо проверять отсутствие `fail`/`bad` битов. Проверка на `eof` приведет к зацикливанию, например, если файл вовсе не удалось открыть. Да и закрывать явно не обязательно, т.к. это сделает деструктор.

Comment: Да вы не поняли все, я знаю как файл считать.. про папку с проектом я имел ввииду папку с исходниками в проекте... то есть вот программа есть у нас 1.exe лежит в папке porga.. Мне надо файл читать не из папки proga а чтобы как бы этот файл упаковался вместе с моей программой в один файл

Comment: @ThreadShakur, лучше отредактируйте Ваш вопрос с учетом дополнительной информации из комментария.