# Как можно внедрить resource файлы в программу?

Tags: c++

Например допустим я хочу сделать программу для смены обоев. Есть функция которая может это реализовать, однако если я скину эту программу на другой компьютер, функция естественно работать не будет, так как на том компьютере нет файла картинки для обоев. Так вот, как можно решить эту проблему?

У меня была идея с sfx архивом, но были проблемы при запросе прав администратора.

Comment: Вам следует перекидывать картинку вместо с программой. Если хочется вшить файл прямо в программу то это можно сделать в виде обычного ресурса.

Comment: @VTT Как раз меня и интересует способ про вшитие файла в программу, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Укажите нужный файл в качестве ресурса и все. Или тут речь идет не о Windows, а о какой-то другой системе? Непонятно в чем вопрос.

Comment: sfx архиву самому по себе для распаковки не требуются права администратора, если конечно вы не захотите его распаковать например в Program Files. Но и просто для копирования программы в Program Files будут нужны права администратора. По поводу добавления в ресурсы - для того чтобы указать картинку как фон рабочего стола, все равно придется ее извлечь, а это уже не сильно будет отличаться от sfx архива.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Включение файла данных в исполняемый файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547115/%d0%92%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)

Comment: можно просто взять любой файл и кодировать его в строку из байтов "FA0A00BC01...", строку объявить константой в проекте и использовать когда нужно. Но если вы пользуетесь msvc/qt то используйте предлагаемые ими ресурсные системы

Answer (score 1):

Надо каким-нибудь конвертором преобразовать картинку в XPM формат, это просто массив на C. Ну и включить его в программу.