# Компиляция независимого .exe вместе с изображением

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Можно ли как-то скомпилировать проект вместе с изображением .png в 1 .exe, чтобы его можно было запустить на другом компьютере?

Comment: используйте самораспаковывающиеся архивы - там есть возможность указать, что запустить после распаковки. Или пихайте все в ресурсы

Comment: То есть все изображения пихать в "файлы ресурсов" проекта?

Comment: Возьмите бинарник и распишите его в виде массива с++ char array[]={0x01,0xab,...}; А потом просто включите массив в проект и слинкуйтесь с ним. Есть утилиты, которые так делают. Если не найдете, то самим можно написать такую утилиту. :-) Но для винды конечно правильнее пихать в ресурсы.

Comment: @Bamberghh а может стоит задуматься о инсталляторе.

Comment: Собрать ваш любой бинарный файл как объект, и слинковать его с программой. Например `ld -r -b binary -o foo1.o foo1.png`

Comment: @NewView Угу, вот тут даже гайд есть: https://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/linking-a-binary-blob-with-gcc/ Но автор собирает студией, а у нее вроде линкер другой, свой.

Comment: В студии очевидно что проще всего класть в ресурсы, не кроссплатформенно, но и не обсуждаемо :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Включение файла данных в исполняемый файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547115/%d0%92%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)