# Как создать PNG изображение через exe. чтобы позже на него можно было ссылаться через программу ( С++ )

Tags: c++, файлы, winapi, windows-10, пк

Я поставил задачу **создать программу**, которая **заменяет фон windows** на заранее заготовленную **картинку** через С++. Также нужно чтобы она **срабатывала на другом ПК** (получается забавный троян).

ВAЖНО:

> **Не должно быть ничего кроме одного exe.**

Здесь появляется проблема: картинка должна как-то хранится и я не понимаю как.

Возможно можно как-то побайтно скопировать ее, и на основе этого создать массив...
В общем буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: В ресурс. Или просто массивом байтов... Потом писать в файл.

Comment: Хорошо, приму к сведенью. Спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Включение файла данных в исполняемый файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547115/%d0%92%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)